# clean-webpack-plugin only accepts an options object

Tags: webpack

I'm getting

> Error: clean-webpack-plugin only accepts an options object. See:
>     https://github.com/johnagan/clean-webpack-plugin#options-and-defaults-

My Webpack.config.js file looks like this:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

var plugins = [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(['dist'], {}),
    new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([{
        from: './src/images/',
        to: './images/'
    }]),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        inject: false,
        template: 'src/index.html'
    })
];

var config = {
    entry: [
        './src/js/main.js'
    ],

    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
        publicPath: '/',
        filename: 'js/bundle.js',
    },

    plugins: plugins.concat([
        new ExtractTextPlugin('css/bundle.css'),
        //new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin(require('./uglifyjs.json'))
    ]),
    devServer: {
        inline: true,
        port: 8080
    },

    module: {
        loaders: [{
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            include: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
            loader: 'babel',
            query: {
                presets: ['react', 'es2015']
            }},
            {
                test: /.s?css$/,
                include: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', [
                    'css?sourceMap',
                    'postcss',
                    'sass?sourceMap'
                ])
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                include: path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules'),
                loader: 'style!css'
            }
        ]
    },
    postcss: function() {
        return [
            require('autoprefixer')({
                browsers: ['last 2 versions']
            })
        ];
    }
}
module.exports = config;
```

Comment: the error says what is wrong. Show also your webpack config. Without it we don't have crystal balls

Comment: Not on the comment section '-'. Edit your question and post it!

Answer (score 13):

As you can see from [the page the error message links](https://github.com/johnagan/clean-webpack-plugin#options-and-defaults-optional), `CleanWebpackPlugin` does not accept two arguments as you're passing in:

```
new CleanWebpackPlugin(['dist'], {}),
```

Instead, just try

```
new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
```

if you don't need to pass in any options.

You may be seeing this problem if you're, say, following an older tutorial or such which uses a different version of the plugin, and the interface has changed meanwhile.

Answer (score 2):

Like @AKX mentioned, newest version of `clean-webpack-plugin` doesn't accept array argument anymore.

The path which should be clearing is reading from webpack's `output.path`. In your example code it's here:

```
output: {
  path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
  // rest of code
},
```

You should be very carefull, because someones still use pattern like this:

```
output: {
  path: __dirname,
  filename: './dist/bundle.js'
},
```

Above configuration will cause removing all files in your project!

If you need to clear only some files from webpack's `output.path` you should set `cleanOnceBeforeBuildPatterns` field in object passed into `CleanWebpackPlugin` constructor.